# ASP.NET MVC Site Map Provider Breaks Under Heavy Load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I have an issue with the ASP.NET MVC Site Map provider and it is causing alot of headaches for me. The issue comes when the server is under heavy load the URL is resolved incorrectly. I have just upgraded to the latest version (3.1.0 RC) where i hoped this would be fixed but unfortunately it hasn't.

I tried to produce a local test to verify this but i was unable to replicate the load on the server. Therefore i will show you a unit test i fire against the live server:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ForumTopic_Breadcrumb() {
    // Arrange
    var isValid = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        try {
            // Send the request
            var request = Http.WebRequest("http://www.mysite.com/Forum/ViewTopic/38044"); // Http.WebRequest is a utility method to send a request to the server and retrieve the content (Note: now the question has been answered i have remove the reference to the actual site)

            // Parse the html document
            var document = new HtmlDocument(); // HTML Agility Pack
            document.LoadHtml(request.Data);

            // Get the required info
            var forumNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='breadcrumb']/a[@href='/Forum/ViewForum/1']");
            var topicNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='breadcrumb']/span");

            // Test if the info is valid
            if (forumNode == null || topicNode.InnerText != "Test Topic")
                throw new Exception();
        } catch {
            isValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Asset
    Assert.IsTrue(isValid);
}
```

This test fails as often the wrong breadcrumb and/or title is displayed.

My ViewTopic action method has the following code in it:

```
// Override the parent node title and url
SiteMap.CurrentNode.ParentNode.Title = topic.Forum.ForumName;
SiteMap.CurrentNode.ParentNode.Url = Url.GenerateUrl("ViewForum", new { id = topic.Forum.ForumID });

// Set the meta description
SiteMap.CurrentNode["MetaDescription"] = topic.Subject;
```

Aswell as having the SiteMapTitle attribute applied to change the current nodes title to the subject of the topic.

I'd really appreciate it if you could help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've received a response from the developer saying that this is due to a limitation with ASP.NET. He hopes to remove this in version 4 by completely segregating out this functionality. Until then the best solution is to override the title by passing it as ViewData.

**Edit** (below is the temporary solution i have come up with):

Create the following SiteMapAttribute.cs file:

```
public class SiteMapAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    protected string TitlePropertyName { get; set; }
    protected string PageTitlePropertyName { get; set; }
    protected string MetaDescriptionPropertyName { get; set; }
    protected string MetaKeywordsPropertyName { get; set; }
    protected string ParentTitlePropertyName { get; set; }

    public SiteMapAttribute() {
    }

    public SiteMapAttribute(string titlePropertyName) {
        TitlePropertyName = titlePropertyName;
    }

    public SiteMapAttribute(string titlePropertyName, string pageTitlePropertyName, string metaDescriptionPropertyName, string metaKeywordsPropertyName)
        : this(titlePropertyName) {
        PageTitlePropertyName = pageTitlePropertyName;
        MetaDescriptionPropertyName = metaDescriptionPropertyName;
        MetaKeywordsPropertyName = metaKeywordsPropertyName;
    }

    public SiteMapAttribute(string titlePropertyName, string pageTitlePropertyName, string metaDescriptionPropertyName, string metaKeywordsPropertyName, string parentTitlePropertyName)
        : this(titlePropertyName, pageTitlePropertyName, metaDescriptionPropertyName, metaKeywordsPropertyName) {
        ParentTitlePropertyName = parentTitlePropertyName;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
        if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult) {
            var result = (ViewResult)filterContext.Result;

            // Get the current node
            var currentNode = filterContext.Controller.GetCurrentSiteMapNode();

            // Make sure the node is found
            if (currentNode != null) {
                // Set the title and meta information (if applicable)
                if (!result.ViewData.ContainsKey("Title"))
                    result.ViewData["Title"] = Resolve(result, TitlePropertyName) ?? currentNode.Title;

                if (!result.ViewData.ContainsKey("PageTitle"))
                    result.ViewData["PageTitle"] = Resolve(result, PageTitlePropertyName) ?? (currentNode["PageTitle"] ?? currentNode.Title);

                if (!result.ViewData.ContainsKey("MetaDescription"))
                    result.ViewData["MetaDescription"] = Resolve(result, MetaDescriptionPropertyName) ?? currentNode["MetaDescription"];

                if (!result.ViewData.ContainsKey("MetaKeywords"))
                    result.ViewData["MetaKeywords"] = Resolve(result, MetaKeywordsPropertyName) ?? currentNode["MetaKeywords"];

                if (!result.ViewData.ContainsKey("ParentTitle"))
                    result.ViewData["ParentTitle"] = Resolve(result, ParentTitlePropertyName);
            }
        }
    }

    private string Resolve(ViewResult result, string propertyName) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            return null;

        var target = ResolveTarget(result.ViewData.Model, propertyName);

        if (target == null)
            target = ResolveTarget(result.ViewData, propertyName);

        return target != null ? target.ToString() : null;
    }

    private object ResolveTarget(object target, string expression) {
        try {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(target.GetType(), "target");
            var lambdaExpression = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { parameter }, null, "target." + expression);
            return lambdaExpression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(target);
        } catch {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You then need to make sure all of your controllers have this attribute applied. In ASP.NET MVC 3 this is alot simpler as you can register this as a global filter.

Now you need to modify the your master page and say something like:

```
<head>
    <title><%= ViewData["PageTitle"] %></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <% if (ViewData["MetaDescription"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewData["MetaDescription"].ToString())) { %>
        <meta name="Description" content="<%= ViewData["MetaDescription"] %>" />
    <% } %>
    <% if (ViewData["MetaKeywords"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewData["MetaKeywords"].ToString())) { %>
        <meta name="Keywords" content="<%= ViewData["MetaKeywords"] %>" />
    <% } %>
</head>
```

Now to patch the breadcrumb (SiteMapPath) i had to get a little hacky. First i created my own helper:

```
/// <summary>
/// MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper extension methods
/// </summary>
public static class SiteMapBreadcrumbExtensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// Source metadata
    /// </summary>
    private static Dictionary<string, object> SourceMetadata = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "HtmlHelper", typeof(SiteMapBreadcrumbExtensions).FullName } };

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets SiteMap path for the current request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="helper">MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper instance</param>
    /// <returns>SiteMap path for the current request</returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString SiteMapBreadcrumb(this MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper) {
        return SiteMapBreadcrumb(helper, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets SiteMap path for the current request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="helper">MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper instance</param>
    /// <param name="templateName">Name of the template.</param>
    /// <returns>SiteMap path for the current request</returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString SiteMapBreadcrumb(this MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper, string templateName) {
        var model = BuildModel(helper, helper.Provider.CurrentNode);

        return helper
            .CreateHtmlHelperForModel(model)
            .DisplayFor(m => model, templateName, new { Title = helper.HtmlHelper.ViewData["Title"], ParentTitle = helper.HtmlHelper.ViewData["ParentTitle"], ParentUrl = helper.HtmlHelper.ViewData["ParentUrl"] });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds the model.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="helper">The helper.</param>
    /// <param name="startingNode">The starting node.</param>
    /// <returns>The model.</returns>
    private static SiteMapPathHelperModel BuildModel(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper, SiteMapNode startingNode) {
        // Build model
        var model = new SiteMapPathHelperModel();
        var node = startingNode;

        while (node != null) {
            var mvcNode = node as MvcSiteMapNode;

            // Check visibility
            var nodeVisible = true;

            if (mvcNode != null)
                nodeVisible = mvcNode.VisibilityProvider.IsVisible(node, HttpContext.Current, SourceMetadata);

            // Check ACL
            if (nodeVisible && node.IsAccessibleToUser(HttpContext.Current))
                model.Nodes.Add(SiteMapNodeModelMapper.MapToSiteMapNodeModel(node, mvcNode, SourceMetadata));

            node = node.ParentNode;
        }

        model.Nodes.Reverse();

        return model;
    }
}
```

The only difference between this and the built in one is that it passes the ViewData to the template. Then finally i created 2 DisplayTemplates:

SiteMapNodeModel.axcx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapNodeModel>" %>
<% if (Model.IsCurrentNode) { %>
    <span class="orange-text"><%= (ViewData["Title"] ?? Model.Title).ToString() %></span>
<% } else if ((bool)ViewData["IsParent"]) { %>
    <a href="<%= (ViewData["ParentUrl"] ?? Model.Url).ToString() %>"><%= (ViewData["ParentTitle"] ?? Model.Title).ToString() %></a>
<% } else { %>
    <a href="<%= Model.Url %>"><%= Model.Title %></a>
<% } %>
```

And SiteMapPathHelperModel.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapPathHelperModel>" %>
<% for (var i = 0; i < Model.Nodes.Count(); i++) { %>
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Nodes[i], new { isParent = Model.Count() - 2 == i }) %>
    <% if (Model.Nodes[i] != Model.Last()) { %>
        &gt;
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

You can now say the following within your view to display the overridden breadcrumb:

```
<%= Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapBreadcrumb() %>
```

With that done now you just need to know how to override the meta/breadcrumb information for a particular action. The easiest way to do this is to override the SiteMapAttribute for a particular action e.g.

```
[SiteMap("Subject", "Subject", "Subject", "", "Forum.ForumName")]
public ActionResult ViewTopic(int id, [DefaultValue(1)] int page) {
}
```

This will set the title, page title, meta information and parent title accordingly. If you would like the title bound to something more complicated than a single property you could set this within the action method by saying something like:

```
ViewData["Title"] = "My Title - " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString();
```

Hope this helps.